# Using Saltstack cmd.script with args to Insert Jinja Variable

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I am running a powershell script to obtain a particular user's credentials, and then use those credentials in a salt state. This works fine when the username is hardcoded directly in the powershell script. But, I am unable to pass the username as an argument. Here is my salt state:

```
{% set creds = salt['cmd.powershell']('C:\test2.ps1' 'username') %}

test_output:
  cmd.run:
    - name: echo {{ creds }}
```

I have also tried this too...but it doesn't work.

```
{% set creds = salt['cmd.script'](shell='powershell' source='C:\test2.ps1' args='username') 
%}
```

How do i correctly pass an argument to my powershell script to set my variable?

Comment: I don’t use powershell cmd function. But I think you forget a comma at the Powershell command

Comment: @SynPrime where did i forget a comma? I don't see it.

Comment: {% set creds = salt['cmd.powershell']('C:\test2.ps1', 'username') %} try this

Comment: `cmd.script` should work, though for `source` parameter you'll have to use the path to script on Salt master. Also you may edit the question and include the actual error/output you are getting with your approach.

Comment: This worked for me:  ```{% set creds = salt['cmd.run']('C:\\test2.ps1 username', shell='powershell') %}``` . Note the backslash needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules for strings and function calls are the same in Jinja as for Python. Either `"` or `'` are the string delimiters, and `\` is the escape character. Function arguments are separated by commas.

```
{% set creds = salt['cmd.powershell']('C:\\test2.ps1 username') %}
```

For `cmd.script`, the `source` should be a remote URL, not a local file.

```
{% set creds = salt['cmd.script'](shell='powershell', source='salt://path/test2.ps1', args='username') %}
```